# How to check for a duplicate row before inserting using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**MYSQL** (attendance) Table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ID | EmployeeID | Name | TimeIn | TimeOut | Date     |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
| 4  | 7          | Jack |   4    |    16   | 18-11-16 |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
| 5  | 7          | Jack |   4    |    16   | 19-11-16 |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
| 6  | 8          | Dave |   4    |    16   | 19-11-16 |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
```

**PHP code to insert a new row:**

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO attendance (ID, EmployeeID, Name, TimeIn, TimeOut, Date) VALUES ('$ID', '$EmployeeID', '$Name', '$TimeIn', '$TimeOut', '$Date');";

$Results = mysql_query($SQL);

if (!$Results){
echo "Error inserting data.";
}
```

According to my code, the user can record same row (same attendance) for the same employee and in the same time (duplicate) like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ID | EmployeeID | Name | TimeIn | TimeOut | Date     |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
| 6  | 8          | Dave |   4    |    16   | 19-11-16 |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
| 7  | 8          | Dave |   4    |    16   | 19-11-16 |
+----+------------+------+--------+---------+----------+
```

How to make sure I'm not inserting the same row twice?

Please let me know if you need more information. 
I appreciate your help.

Comment: set a UNIQUE constraint or check if it exists first

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your `ID` column is a unique primary key.  And then you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO attendance (ID, EmployeeID, Name, TimeIn, TimeOut, Date) VALUES ('$ID', '$EmployeeID', '$Name', '$TimeIn', '$TimeOut', '$Date') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (EmployeeID=VALUES(EmployeeID),Name=VALUES(Name);";
```

...and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The way to go here is to set a [sql unique constrain](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on the columns that should be unique. You need to do this in the database. Then Check for an exception in your PHP Code, when you try to insert a new row.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be using `mysql_query` as it's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Instead, you can use [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (for example).

To answer your question, your ID should be unique (this is a common thing). Once it's unique, you can then check if your insertion was successful or not (with `if`, for example).

Comment: The ID is unique already. Even if the ID is unique, the user will still be able to duplicate the same row but only with a different ID, for example, the user will be able to record the attendance of the same employee in the same date.

Comment: @the7k What will definitely work, is to use `select` query first instead of `insert into`. If you get at least one row, then it means all values are duplicated and you skip the insertion process.